# how to check next existence of a character in string in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi All I have a string like this

```
var data='mobile,car,soap,room';
```

I am parsing from this string and making this string as comma sperated and pushing it into an array like this

```
var availableTags=[];
var str='';
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
  if(data[i]==',')
  {    
    availableTags .push(str);
    str='';
  }
  else
  {
    str +=data[i];
  }
}
```

But I am doing wrong as I cannot get the last value after comma... Now What I want to ask how can I come to know the next existence of `,` in my string that whether it exists or not. So that I can also include the last value.

I would also appreciate if someone guide me that how can I accomplish that same task some other way.

I want the string to be an array and it should look like this

```
  ["mobile","car","soap","room"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
data.split(/,/)
```

See the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) documentation.

Answer (score 4):

you can use

```
var availableTags = data.split(",");
```

it will handle all the things. and will result in an array.

Answer (score 1):

After loop, you need to check value of `str` and add it too. It can contain the rest after last comma, or it can be empty in case comma was the last character in `data`.

But as other pointed, `split` is probably better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as fixing your existing function, try adding the following after the `for` loop:

```
if (str != "")
   availableTags.push(str);
```

(When the loop ends `str` holds whatever came after the last comma.)

But like the other answers said, you can just use the array `.split()` method:

```
var availableTags = data.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could append an extra comma on at the start:

```
data = data + ","
```

...

Comment: And in case the original string's last character was comma, then he'll get empty string as last element of resulting array

Comment: indeed. yes. that's true. (am I at 15 characters yet?)